# Is there such a thing as a programmable power sink?

Tags: power, test-equipment

Is there such a thing as a power sink equivalent to a benchtop power supply, where I can set the wattage (voltage, amperage) to be consumed?

What is this device called?

Comment: Two-quadrant power supply, at least. Look over this [page](https://www.accelinstruments.com/Applications/TS200/Four-Quadrant.html). I think it will become clear.

Comment: Active load hp/Agilent/keysight 6060b if you have the budget and the bench space.

Comment: This is a bit like asking if there's a device out there that can somehow measure a voltage. A quick google should have solved it (since you work there). Every manufacturer of electronic test gear makes these. "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: There's a recent youtube [video](https://youtu.be/hzKE4-yhRKo) by electronicsNmore discharging some LiFePO4 batteries through a recording Electronic Load.

Comment: electronic load, If you feel they are costly, You can make one if you need this frequently,

Comment: heater might work if you can dump generated heat somewhere and thus keep temperature stable enough

Comment: @user19579 Why did you feel the need to repeat the previous answers so much that you had to break the policy and write a comment answering the question?

Comment: @pipe: I need to mention if he needs he can do a small PCB for it. If it is offending any body. I will not add it next onwards.

Comment: Many multichemistry battery chargers have dischargers also inbuilt. Primarily used by RC customers. You could search for lipo charger on banggood, and pick one with good enough discharge rating. Most of these allow to control discharge current. Some have a USB interface that can show charge/dischare graph over time in their own app.

Comment: @user19579 It's a good comment but would go better as a comment on the answer. We use comments if we think something needs to be changed in either the question or the answer. so your contribution about making an electronic load is good, but if you had put it as a comment on the answer it would be more in the spirit of stack exchange. This is what pipe means but they said it a bit bluntly.

Comment: @Segfault: Got it. I can't explain properly in English. But these small things will help me to be in right path. thanks

Comment: @pipe, this question is the top hit for "programmable power sink"! ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes there is, it is called an electronic load.

Comment: the was an open source one on kickstarter a few years ago... https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/nickjohnson/re-load-pro-a-dc-active-load

Comment: @vicatcu it's really an established thing, and I'm not sure how useful a kickstarter from a few years back in a professional environment is if the shop they link to is down... and 25 W max power? Oh, cute.

Comment: I don't know, awareness of open-source designs is helpful imho

Comment: @vicatcu For that purpose, it might have been more appropriate to link to [the design sources](https://github.com/arachnidlabs/reload-pro/) directly instead of their kickstarter pager.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I didn't have time and that was the first thing that came up when I Google'd so I shared it.

Answer (score 6):

You might be looking for a Programmable Load Bank.